# Javascript/jquery replace text removes formatting of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

http://jsfiddle.net/2EvGF/

JS

```
$('.msgln').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('Admin', 'sys-admin')); 
});
```

HTML

```
<div class='msgln'><b>Admin</b>:<i> Chat cleared</i><br></div>
```

Replacing the class '.msgln' removes the formatting (bold, italics, etc.) How can I resolve this?

Comment: why do you want to remove the class `msgln`

Answer (score 0):

It might be happening because the css rules for `bold, italcs etc` might be defined for the class `msgln`, so once the class is removed the associated css rules also will be removed.

A solution is to add another class where the same css rules are defined

Answer (score 0):

As it said here, http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2, it replace whole inner html with the given text.

You need to get down to the element that has the text you want to replace. In your case, it would be `.msgln b`

```
$('.msgln b').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('Admin', 'sys-admin')); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with sincebasic's solution. Here's my version with little update as you can have  tag presented in other parts of the the HTML with the class "msgln". How about the following?

HTML

```
<div class='msgln'><b><span class="username">Admin</span></b>:<i> Chat cleared</i><br></div>
```

JS

```
$('.msgln span.username').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('Admin', 'sys-admin')); 
});
```